# Setting the reply address using the mail command

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I am running a Fedora Virtual Server

I mail one of my users using the following command inside a bash script

```
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

Inside Virtualmin I have setup main forwarding so all mail from the domain gets sent to my gmail account.  When I get the message is contains no FROM field.  How can I change this to the name of the account on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `/usr/lib/sendmail` with the `-t` flag:

```
/usr/lib/sendmail -t < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

Your file at `$EMAILMESSAGE` should contain the appropriate header lines, followed by a blank line, followed by your message text:

```
To: some.address@mydomain.abc
From: my.address@mydomain.abc
Subject: This is my subject line

The text of my message begins here.
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a cron job that emails me the output of another program once a day, which I have to check for changes from the previous day. By using your method to manually set headers, I set the In-Reply-To and References headers. This causes Gmail to treat the messages as a conversation thread, which is great because Gmail automatically highlights the changes for me, hiding unchanged text behind "Show quoted text". So now I am using Gmail as a diff tool :) I put this here because I could find no info on using In-Reply-To with the `mail` command, and others may benefit if it is here.